# JPA repository queries by function name for not equals

Tags: spring, jpa, crud

I'm trying to write a query by function name available in Spring (JPA). I need something like this `select * from table where col1=x AND col2=y AND col3 <> z`. Would the following function name be equivalent?

`findByCol1AndColb2ndCol3IsNot(....)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

findByCol1AndCol2AndCol3Not -> you just need to remove the "Is" . The following page lists all the possible keywords:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: Got it. I was under the impression Not at the end negates the whole statement